# What page builds first?

Tags: next.js

I need to call getStaticProps method on a build before other pages will start building. So is there any way to set what page needs to build first or set getStaticProps method somewhere before pages will build?

My goal is to create a file on build and update it with 'revalidate' option. An that needs to be done before other pages will build

Comment: will you create it for every page build or a single file for everything? If it is a single file, will you update the file on every build? Also remember Vercel doesn't support file systems by default

Comment: @Obed oh i didn't know that Vercel doesn't support a file system. Basically, I need to get data from this file on the build for some pages and revalidate the data. I will need to update the file on every build. 

My problem is: I have a lot of pages and for these pages, I need the same data from an API. For example, I have 10 pages and I have API calls in getStaticProps for these 10 pages. It's 10 calls. Instead, I want to do one and store the data in the file. Then just get data from the file if I need

Comment: This GH discussion might shed some light on possible solutions: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11272.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer your question, I want to note that, the calls in the getStatic props are evaluated on build time, as a result not affected when a user visits the page, therefore, as long as you do not rebuild the application, the total calls that will happen is just 10. When a user visits the page, it will not make the `getStaticProps` again.

From this [article](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions) you may have to modify your configurations to allow that.

Now lets look at some ways you can achieve what you are saying.

**A pre build hook.**

This can be done outside of the next basically, you can add your code to a  file lets say `script.js` and add a prebuild hook which should run before you build. you can specify this hook in your `package.json`.
PS. This might not run on `revalidate`You might need further investigation

```
  "prebuild": "node script.js",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
```

**in the `./pages/_app.js` file.**

You can modify the get static props in the app.js file. You only do this if you do not need the automatic static page generation. ie, you should explicitly state that the page should be statically generated in subsequent pages by adding a `getStaticProps`. You can find out more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app). And I will add a quote from there.

> Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
> every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
> perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app
> to be server-side rendered.

```
import App from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  // you can put your file stuff here
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  return { ...appProps }
}

export default MyApp
```

Let me know how it goes in the comment, i will gladly help out more if i can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I understand that my file will be updated only on build or with revalidating option. This is what I want. With prebuild functionality it works, but I still need to revalidate the code and update the file. With _app it's great but as far as I know, I cant use getStaticProps there. Only getInitialProps. And this is now what I need

Comment: I tried to check around, but there is no documentation of what page builds first. What came to mind was, depending on your use case, you can use a hybrid method, where you first use the prebuild to load the content, and add the fetch to a single page's `getStaticProps`. this will mean there ill always be some content, though some will be out of sync @NickBukovskiy